# Saving HTML characters

Tags: fckeditor

Using FCKEditor

We are trying to place the clubs character into the database and bring it back out.  The first couple times, the character is saved correctly, but after a couple of edits to the file the html encoding of the clubs character is being lost when saved to the database.

Any ideas?

version 2.3.1

Comment: don't use FCKeditor http://secureyes.net/nw/assets/File-Upload-Vulnerability-in-FCKEditor.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer...   updated to newest version and the problem was corrected.